# Mechanism for Identifying Ads on a Webpage [Specifically AdBlock]

Tags: python, open-source, web-crawler, ads, adblock

I am currently doing a research project and I am attempting to figure out a good way to identify ads given access to the html of a webpage.

I thought it might be a good idea to start with AdBlock. AdBlock is a program that prevents ads from being displayed to the user, so presumably it has a mechanism for identifying things as ads.

I downloaded the source code for AdBlockPlus, but I find myself completely lost in all of the files. I am not sure where to start looking for this detection mechanism, so I was wondering if anyone had any advice on where to start. Alternatively if you have dealt with AdBlock before and are familiar with it, I would appreciate any extra information.

For example, if the webpage needs to be rendered in a real browser to use Adblock, there are programs that will automate the loading of a webpage so this wouldn't be a problem but I am not sure how to figure out if this is what AdBlock does in the first place.

Note: AdBlock is written in Python and Perl :)

Thanks!

Comment: No, you don't really need to render the elements in order to use Adblock. All you need are the filter rules which can be applied on the URLs of HTML elements to check if they are ads or not

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you to first have a look at writing [adblock filter rules](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters).

Then, once you get an idea of this, you can start parsing [adblock lists](http://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) available in various languages to suit your needs.

Comment: Oh thank you! One other question: you mention "adblock lists," they call them "subscriptions," which "are lists of filters," for example: https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt

However, it simply looks like a list of URLs. Are filters limited to the idea of listing a URL (perhaps with a wildcard *)?

Comment: In addition, you do have [## rules](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters#elemhide) for identifying ads in HTML elements. You also have regex support(although not recommended for performance reasons) and rules need not always include host names. You can also whitelist using [@@](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters#whitelist). But overall, the rules are pretty simple though.

Comment: Do you happen to know what this means: widget.shopstyle.com/widget?pid=$subdocument,third-party
It has a comma, and I was unable to find what it means in the filter rules you linked me to.

Comment: things after the $ are options. see the adblock filter rules link.